# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Woodworking's [first moderator election](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a closeand the new moderator is:

[image: Ashlar]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking drs who will be stepping down as moderator.

Since this is a [*pro tempore* election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections), there was no need for it to be competitive. With only one nomination, we skipped the vote.

Comment: @drs thank you for getting this site kicked off, and for serving as a moderator!

Answer (score 2):

Ashlar, congrats and thank you for volunteering!

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a lot on this site (especially by answering questions)!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Moderators.  Obviously I am not on here as much as I want to be...